# Getting a blurry screen before loading

Tags: 16.04, screen

System operates normally. The only issue is that after login for a couple of seconds I get this on my screen:

[image]

How do I fix it?

Turns out, I had to have my wallpaper on Ubuntu disc :)

Comment: Of course, the flippant answer would be "wait a few seconds for it to go away." 

What kind of graphics card does your computer have?

Comment: @NickWeinberg product: GM108M [GeForce 840M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation

Comment: Yup, it's most likely due to Nvidia drivers. I had the same issue after installing nvidias propriotary drivers. For me, it catastrophically broke everything else too, so I reverted back to nouveau driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had to have my wallpaper on Ubuntu disc :)